# Use a form in a view component or a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm using the .net core framework with razor pages without MVC and I'm trying to integrate a form with a view component to make it reusable.

The problem is I noticed that it's not really made for. Indeed I use the **asp-for** attribute of the form which in reality is based on the parent **PageModel** in which I have bound an attribute corresponding to the field of my form.

I would like to know how you can create reusable component that contain forms to be used in a final **PageModel**.

Thank you :)

Comment: All web frameworks push standard HTML, CSS, Javascript and WASM to the browser. There is no reason you cannot create plain old input elements and post the form to a controller. The Controller's model binder will try to use those fields, or you can access the data as form values too.

Comment: Precisely the data are bound to the parent controller and not to the view component ; that's the problem and I wish I had a workaround
I think that you should not use the asp-for attribute and therefore get the data as a parameter but the documention is not very informative on this subject

Comment: To try to be clearer I just want to be able to bind the asp-for attribute of a form inside a view component to an attribute of a parent class ModelPage via [BindProperty]
I started to find a track [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297108/multiple-view-components-in-net-core-razor-page-not-binding-correctly) but it's not super clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your partial view reusable,it means only one model should be called.

Do you want to use a partial view, and get the data from different models?

Then you can use a **ViewModel** to contain multiple different models,like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
public class Profile
{      
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
//....other models
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
    public MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        MyViewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            Job = new Job { Name = "teacher" },
            Profile=new Profile {Name="Peter"}          
        };
    }
```

Index.cshtml (**model=** is used to pass model to partial):

```
<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/Partialview.cshtml" model="Model.MyViewModel" />
```

Then you can get the related model data in Partial view:

```
@model tr4cks491.Models.MyViewModel
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Job.Name" />
    <input asp-for="Profile.Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Indeed it works. In fact I was trying to pass a string directly and couldn't. I'm new to this framework so I'm still confused about some principles.
But if you want to do the same thing for view components I advise you to read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297108/multiple-view-components-in-net-core-razor-page-not-binding-correctly) because there are conflicts when you use several components in the same page.